# Loop until list is not empty in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm working on a web scrapper that has two classes. One takes the data and the other class processes it. The end result of the first class is a list of elements such as `results = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]` . The problem is sometimes, due to server-side error, the list can come out empty. How can I loop through this to restart the process until the list is not empty?

I kinda solved it like this. But I'm not sure if this is efficient or a good practice.

```py
class DataScrapper:
      def __init__(self):
         ...
      
      def getData(self):
         self.results = []
         while not self.results:
              ...
         return self.results
```

Is this a pythonic way of solving the problem? Is there another more efficient way? Thank you very much.

Comment: it seems more a businuss logic, other than python technical problem.

Comment: If `...` is a server side call this may get you blacklisted due to too many requests to the server. You may be better off accepting the empty list and give that as a return - or raise an exception.

Comment: This seems like a good and explicit approach. You might want to add a delay between attempts and a max number of tries, but this looks good.

Comment: Take a look at this short API guide from AWS (suggests just what the commenters above me suggest): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html

Comment: Thank you everyone! I will keep this things on my mind while refactoring the code. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idiom is simple and good for most cases.

You must however keep in mind of 2 things:

1. You don't cap the retries. If the server is down for a long time, your script will get stuck.
2. You keep on generating requests even during downtimes. That can cause a large client and server load. I highly suggest using an exponential backoff strategy.

A quick search in google found the [backoff](https://github.com/litl/backoff) library which allows you to do both:

```
@backoff.on_predicate(backoff.expo, lambda x: x == [], max_tries=10)
def getData(self):
     self.results = []
     ...
     return self.results
```

It  checks the return value, and if it's an empty list, runs the function again with increasing delays until you reach 10 tries.

Comment: Thank you very time for your time and suggestion! I'll try this :)